Python Tkinter program quitting after clicking button
I'm making a project on airline reservation system. I created a login page and signup page using Tkinter. I created a button in login page to go to signup page and vice-versa. The problem is when I click on the button "signup" in login page to go to signup and then click the button "back to login" on signup page and again click on "signup" in login, the program quits.
Here is the login page
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

import mysql.connector

win=Tk()
win.title("AirWaves")
win.geometry('1366x768')
win.geometry("+100+50")
win.configure(bg="#fff")
win.resizable(False,False)


def clear():
    uentry.delete(0, END)
    pentry.delete(0, END)

def login():
    db=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", database='jagran', user='root', password='1074')
    cur=db.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from passengers where username = (%s) and password = (%s)", (uentry.get(),pentry.get()))
    if (cur.fetchone()):
        messagebox.showinfo("✅", "Login Success!!!")
        win.destroy()
        import app
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Login Failed ❌", "The username or password you have entered is incorrect. Please try again.")

def signup():
    win.destroy()
    import signup


img = PhotoImage(file="airplane aesthetics.png", master=win)
Label(win,image=img,bg='white', anchor="nw").place(x=-2,y=-2)

h1 = Label(win , text = "AirWaves" , font = 'Perpetua 80 bold', bg="#fff")
h1.place(x=770 , y=60)

h2 = Label(win , text = "Airline Reservation System" , font = 'Perpetua 30 bold', bg="#fff")
h2.place(x=755 , y=160)

uname = Label(win , text = "Username" , font = 'Perpetua 25 bold', bg="#fff")
uname.place(x=755 , y=300)

pswrd = Label(win , text = "Password" , font = 'Perpetua 25 bold', bg="#fff")
pswrd.place(x=755 , y=350)

h3 = Label(win , text = "Dont't have an Account?" , font = 'Perpetua 25 bold', bg="#fff")
h3.place(x=800 , y=550)

username = StringVar()
password = StringVar()

uentry = Entry(win, font = 'Perpetua 25 bold', bg="#fff", textvariable=username)
uentry.place(x=920, y=300)

pentry = Entry(win, font = 'Perpetua 25 bold', bg="#fff", textvariable=password)
pentry.place(x=920, y=350)

b1 = Button(win, text="Clear", width=7, font='Carrier 15', command=clear)
b1.place(x=920,y=410)

b2 = Button(win, text="Login", width=7, font='Carrier 15', command=login)
b2.place(x=1135,y=410)

b3 = Button(win, text="Signup", width=7, font='Carrier 15', command=signup)
b3.place(x=920,y=620)

win.mainloop()

Here is the signup page
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter import ttk
import mysql.connector

win2=Tk()
win2.title("AirWaves")
win2.geometry('1366x768')
win2.geometry("+100+50")
win2.configure(bg="#fff")
win2.resizable(False, False)

def clear():
    fname.delete(0, END)
    lname.delete(0, END)
    dob.delete(0, END)
    pportno.delete(0, END)
    phone.delete(0, END)
    email.delete(0, END)
    username.delete(0, END)
    password.delete(0, END)
    veripass.delete(0, END)

def login():

    win2.destroy()
    import login


def signup():
    fn = fname.get()
    ln = lname.get()
    gen = gender.get()
    age = dob.get()
    ppno = pportno.get()
    em = email.get()
    phn = phone.get()
    uname= username.get()
    passwrd = password.get()
    vp = veripass.get()

    finalpass = ''
    if (vp in passwrd):
        finalpass = vp
    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Password does Not Match')

    tu = (fn, ln, gen, age, ppno, em, phn, uname, finalpass)
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='1074', database='jagran')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    query = "insert into passengers values(%s, %s , %s, %s , %s , %s , %s, %s, %s)"
    cur.execute(query, tu)
    conn.commit()
    messagebox.showinfo('SignUp Success', 'Account Created')


img = PhotoImage(file="signupplane.png", master=win2)
Label(win2, image=img, bg='white', anchor="nw").place(x=420, y=575)

h1 = Label(win2, text ="AirWaves", font ='Perpetua 35 bold', bg="#fff")
h1.place(x=575 , y=5)

h2 = Label(win2, text ="Airline Reservation System", font ='Perpetua 20 bold', bg="#fff")
h2.place(x=530 , y=50)

#Label names
fname = Label(win2, text ="First Name", font ='Perpetua 25 bold', bg="#fff")
fname.place(x=50 , y=140)

lname = Label(win2, text ="Last Name", font ='Perpetua 25 bold', bg="#fff")
lname.place(x=50 , y=220)

gender = Label(win2, text ="Gender", font ='Perpetua 25 bold', bg="#fff")
gender.place(x=50 , y=300)

dob = Label(win2, text ="D.O.B", font ='Perpetua 25 bold', bg="#fff")
dob.place(x=50 , y=380)

pportno = Label(win2, text ="Passport No.", font ='Perpetua 25 bold', bg="#fff")
pportno.place(x=50 , y=460)

phone = Label(win2, text ="Phone", font ='Perpetua 25 bold', bg="#fff")
phone.place(x=780 , y=140)

email = Label(win2, text ="Email", font ='Perpetua 25 bold', bg="#fff")
email.place(x=780 , y=220)

username = Label(win2, text ="Username", font ='Perpetua 25 bold', bg="#fff")
username.place(x=780 , y=300)

password = Label(win2, text ="Password", font ='Perpetua 25 bold', bg="#fff")
password.place(x=780 , y=380)

veripass = Label(win2, text ="Verify Password", font ='Perpetua 25 bold', bg="#fff")
veripass.place(x=780 , y=460)

fname = StringVar()
lname = StringVar()
gender = StringVar()
dob = StringVar()
pportno = StringVar()
phone = StringVar()
email = StringVar()
username = StringVar()
password = StringVar()


#Label name entry
fname = Entry(win2, font ='Perpetua 20 bold', bg="#fff", textvariable=fname)
fname.place(x=250, y=140)

lname = Entry(win2, font ='Perpetua 20 bold', bg="#fff", textvariable=lname)
lname.place(x=250, y=220)

'''gender = Entry(win3, font ='Perpetua 20 bold', bg="#fff", textvariable=gender)
gender.place(x=250, y=300)'''

s=ttk.Style()
s.configure('bg.TRadiobutton', background="#fff", font ='Perpetua 20 bold')
genderm = ttk.Radiobutton(win2, text='Male', value="Male", variable=gender, style='bg.TRadiobutton')
genderm.place(x= 250 , y= 280)
genderf = ttk.Radiobutton(win2, text='Female', value="Female", variable=gender, style='bg.TRadiobutton')
genderf.place(x= 250 , y= 330)

dob = Entry(win2, font ='Perpetua 20 bold', bg="#fff", textvariable=dob)
dob.place(x=250, y=380)

pportno = Entry(win2, font ='Perpetua 20 bold', bg="#fff", textvariable=pportno)
pportno.place(x=250, y=460)

phone = Entry(win2, font ='Perpetua 20 bold', bg="#fff", textvariable=phone)
phone.place(x=1050, y=140)

email = Entry(win2, font ='Perpetua 20 bold', bg="#fff", textvariable=email)
email.place(x=1050, y=220)

username = Entry(win2, font ='Perpetua 20 bold', bg="#fff", textvariable=username)
username.place(x=1050, y=300)

password = Entry(win2, font ='Perpetua 20 bold', bg="#fff", textvariable=password)
password.place(x=1050, y=380)

veripass = Entry(win2, font ='Perpetua 20 bold', bg="#fff", textvariable=veripass)
veripass.place(x=1050, y=460)

#buttons
b1 = Button(win2, text="Clear", width=10, font='Carrier 15', command=clear)
b1.place(x=410,y=525)

b2 = Button(win2, text="Signup", width=10, font='Carrier 15', command=signup)
b2.place(x=600,y=525)

b3 = Button(win2, text="Back to Login", width=13, font='Carrier 15', command=login)
b3.place(x=790,y=525)

win2.mainloop()


Your import ... statements which you try to use to switch between modules only ever work once, which is how import is supposed to work. You need to decide which module is the main one (or create a main module) and have that call functions in the other.

Use switching frames instead of destroying and creating root window.

@acw1668 im not using frames

@quamrana im sorry but can you please show me how to do that

Explanation
When you do import filename Python finds that file and creates a special object called module.
The import process involves loading the module, and as part of the loading, the module is executed (hence the tkinter window appears).
I'm assuming you expected that when you import a filename, it would work the same as when you run the file as a script.
In the case of import, the code will be executed once, during the first import.
Once loaded, a reference to the module will be found in sys.modules.
So, when you import filename a second time, the code doesn't execute.
Demonstration
Suppose we have two files.
login.py
import tkinter as tk
import sys


# this line will be executed in any case    
print("login in sys.modules.keys()", "login" in sys.modules.keys())

# this line will only be executed if we call the "open_signup()" function, just like the "print()" function call above
def open_signup():
    login_root.destroy()
    print("import signup")
    import signup

# this line will be executed in any case
login_root = tk.Tk()

if __name__ == "__main__": # case: python login.py
    print("Start program")
    print("code is executed: login_root created\n")
else: # case: import login
    print("module is loaded, code is executed: login_root created\n")

# these lines will be executed in any case
login_root.title("Login")
l = tk.Label(login_root, text="Login")
l.pack()
b = tk.Button(login_root, text="Go to Sign Up", command=open_signup)
b.pack()
login_root.mainloop() # mainloops are blocking normal program execution

# this will be printed after all windows are closed/destroyed
print("after login_root mainloop")

signup.py
import tkinter as tk
import sys


print("signup in sys.modules.keys()", "signup" in sys.modules.keys())


def open_login():
    signup_root.destroy()
    print("import login")
    import login


signup_root = tk.Tk()
print("module is loaded, code is executed: signup_root created\n")
signup_root.title("Sign Up")
l = tk.Label(signup_root, text="Sign Up")
l.pack()
b = tk.Button(signup_root, text="Go to Login", command=open_login)
b.pack()
signup_root.mainloop()
print("after signup_root mainloop")

Start the program with python login.py. Switch between windows until the program is finished.
Output
login in sys.modules.keys() False
Start program
code is executed: login_root created

import signup
signup in sys.modules.keys() True
module is loaded, code is executed: signup_root created

import login
login in sys.modules.keys() True
module is loaded, code is executed: login_root created

import signup
after login_root mainloop
after signup_root mainloop
after login_root mainloop

As we can see, when all modules are imported once and all GUI windows are destroyed, the program exits.
import signup has no effect a second time.
Multiple Windows
In most cases, one root window is sufficient.
But if you really need multiple Tk windows for login, registration and app it is possible.
You need to rewrite your windows as classes or wrap them in functions. Therefore, they can be imported and used many times.
Start with python main.py.
main.py
import login


def main(): # entry-point
    print("Start program")
    login.create_login()
    print("End")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    main()

app.py
import tkinter as tk

import login


def logout(root):
    root.destroy()
    login.create_login()

    
def create_app(user):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Main")
    root.geometry("+100+50")
    l = tk.Label(root, text="Main Window")
    l.pack()
    l1 = tk.Label(root, text=user)
    l1.pack()
    b = tk.Button(root, text="Log Out", command=lambda: logout(root))
    b.pack()
    root.mainloop()

login.py
import tkinter as tk

import signup
import app


def login_user(login_root, user):
    login_root.destroy()
    app.create_app(user)
    
def open_signup(login_root):
    login_root.destroy()
    signup.create_signup()


def create_login():
    login_root = tk.Tk()
    login_root.title("Login")
    login_root.geometry("+100+50")
    l = tk.Label(login_root, text="Login")
    l.pack()
    b = tk.Button(login_root, text="Go to Sign Up", command=lambda: open_signup(login_root))
    b.pack()
    b1 = tk.Button(login_root, text="Submit Form", command=lambda: login_user(login_root, "Test User"))
    b1.pack()
    img = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"image.png", master=login_root)
    img_label = tk.Label(login_root, image=img)
    img_label.pack()
    img_label.image = img # additional reference to image created in function
    login_root.mainloop()

signup.py
import tkinter as tk

import login
import app


def signup_user(signup_root, user):
    signup_root.destroy()
    app.create_app(user)

def open_login(signup_root):
    signup_root.destroy()
    login.create_login()


def create_signup():
    signup_root = tk.Tk()
    signup_root.title("Sign Up")
    signup_root.geometry("+100+50")
    l = tk.Label(signup_root, text="Sign Up")
    l.pack()
    b = tk.Button(signup_root, text="Go to Login", command=lambda: open_login(signup_root))
    b.pack()
    b1 = tk.Button(signup_root, text="Submit Form", command=lambda: signup_user(signup_root, "Test User"))
    b1.pack()
    img = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"image.png", master=signup_root)
    img_label = tk.Label(signup_root, image=img)
    img_label.pack()
    img_label.image = img # additional reference to image created in function
    signup_root.mainloop()

One Root Window
In this approach, we manage the content of a single window.
You can simply redraw widgets based on user actions.
There are some advantages that apply to your case:

You can define window parameters (geometry, resizing) only once.
You can create one style object for all ttk widgets.
You can define common elements, such as headers, for all views only once.

Start with python main.py.
main.py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

import login_view


def main(): # entry-point
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.title("AirWaves")
    win.configure(bg="#fff")
    win.geometry("+100+50")

    style = ttk.Style(win)
    style.configure('bg.TRadiobutton', background="#fff")
    style.configure('header.TLabel', background="#fff", anchor="center")
    
    h1 = ttk.Label(win, text="AirWaves", style='header.TLabel')
    h1.pack(fill="both")
    h2 = ttk.Label(win, text="Airline Reservation System", style='header.TLabel')
    h2.pack(fill="both")
    
    main_frame = tk.Frame(win, bg="#fff")
    main_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    # default view
    login_view.create_login_view(main_frame)

    win.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    main()

main_view.py
import tkinter as tk

import login_view


def create_main_view(parent, username):
    for i in parent.winfo_children():
        i.destroy()

    uname = tk.Label(parent, text=username)
    uname.grid(row=0, column=0)
    b = tk.Button(parent, text="Log Out", command=lambda: login_view.create_login_view(parent))
    b.grid(row=1, column=0)

login_view.py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

import signup_view
import main_view


def login_user(parent, username, password):
    # check username and password in db
    if username.get() and password.get():
        main_view.create_main_view(parent, username.get())
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Login Failed ❌",
                             "The username or password you have entered is incorrect. Please try again.")

   
def create_login_view(parent):
    for i in parent.winfo_children():
        i.destroy()

    def clear_login_entries():
        uentry.delete(0, tk.END)
        pentry.delete(0, tk.END)

    img = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"image.png", master=parent.master)
    img_label = tk.Label(parent, image=img)
    img_label.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4)
    img_label.image = img # additional reference to image created in function
    
    uname = tk.Label(parent, text="Username")
    uname.grid(row=0, column=1)
    pswrd = tk.Label(parent, text="Password")
    pswrd.grid(row=1, column=1)
    uentry = tk.Entry(parent)
    uentry.grid(row=0, column=2)
    pentry = tk.Entry(parent)
    pentry.grid(row=1, column=2)
    b = tk.Button(parent, text="Login", command=lambda: login_user(parent, uentry, pentry))
    b.grid(row=2, column=2)
    b2 = tk.Button(parent, text="Go to Sign Up", command=lambda: signup_view.create_signup_view(parent))
    b2.grid(row=3, column=2)
    b3 = tk.Button(parent, text="Clear", command=clear_login_entries)
    b3.grid(row=4, column=2)

signup_view.py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

import login_view
import main_view

    
def signup_user(parent, username, password, veripass):
    # check values and save to the database
    if all([username.get(), password.get(), veripass.get()]):
        main_view.create_main_view(parent, username.get())
    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Something went wrong.')
    
    
def create_signup_view(parent):
    for i in parent.winfo_children():
        i.destroy()

    def clear_signup_entries():
        uentry.delete(0, tk.END)
        pentry.delete(0, tk.END)
        vpentry.delete(0, tk.END)
        gender.set("")
     
    uname = tk.Label(parent, text="Username" )
    uname.grid(row=0, column=0)
    pswrd = tk.Label(parent, text="Password")
    pswrd.grid(row=1, column=0)
    veripass = tk.Label(parent, text="Verify Password")
    veripass.grid(row=2, column=0)
    uentry = tk.Entry(parent)
    uentry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    pentry = tk.Entry(parent)
    pentry.grid(row=1, column=1)
    vpentry = tk.Entry(parent)
    vpentry.grid(row=2, column=1)
    gender = tk.StringVar()
    genderm = ttk.Radiobutton(parent, text='Male', value="Male", variable=gender, style='bg.TRadiobutton')
    genderm.grid(row=3, column=1)
    genderf = ttk.Radiobutton(parent, text='Female', value="Female", variable=gender, style='bg.TRadiobutton')
    genderf.grid(row=4, column=1)
    b = tk.Button(parent, text="Sign Up", command=lambda: signup_user(parent, uentry, pentry, vpentry))
    b.grid(row=5, column=1)
    b2 = tk.Button(parent, text="Go to Login", command=lambda: login_view.create_login_view(parent))
    b2.grid(row=6, column=1)
    b3 = tk.Button(parent, text="Clear", command=clear_signup_entries)
    b3.grid(row=7, column=1)

